# What is the best practise for controlling the size of Angular Material dialog?

Tags: angular-material

I want to know whether controlling the size (height, width) of dialog via CSS is preferred over specifying the size of dialog in TS file itself? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practise to control the size of an Angular Material dialog is via `MatDialogConfig`. **You will have more control with this config than with CSS, since you don't need to override Angular Material's CSS classes**. In this config ([see Angular Material Dialog API docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig)) in your component, you can specify the needs for the size of your dialog:

```js
height: string
maxHeight: number | string
maxWidth: number | string
minHeight: number | string
minWidth: number | string
width: string
```

You can pass this information as second argument inside the `.open()` method of your dialog.

Example ([see StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1m21na?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-content-example.ts)):

```js
const dialogConfig = {
     maxHeight: '300px',
     maxWidth: '300px',
}
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog, dialogConfig);
```

Here the dialog will have a `max-width` and `max-height` of both `300px`.

If you want to display different dialogs based on the user's screen width, you can use the `BreakpointObserver` from [Angular's CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/api).

Example ([see StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t8axh2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-content-example.ts)):

1. Import BreakpointObserver and add it to constructor.

```js
import { BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}
```

2. Add a function that calculates the dialog dimensions

```js
getDialogDimensions() {
    const mobileDialogConfig = {
        maxHeight: '300px',
        maxWidth: '300px'
    };

    const desktopDialogConfig = {
        maxHeight: '600px',
        maxWidth: '300px'
    };

    const isMobile = this.breakpointObserver.isMatched('(max-width: 600px)');
    return isMobile ? mobileDialogConfig : desktopDialogConfig;
}
```

3. Add this function as second inside the `.open()` method of the dialog.

```js
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog, this.getDialogDimensions());
```

4. Outcome

[image: Small dialog]

[image: Larger dialog]